# UseStaticFiles outside of wwwroot and make them publicly available

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

My understanding is that specifying a StaticFiles path from middleware will allow for public access even if the files sit outside wwwroot, as long as the StaticFiles are specified before the Authorization/Authentication middleware calls.

So for example the following should make the static files accessible publicly

```
 void ConfigureMiddleware(IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceProvider services, IHostEnvironment environment) {
      
  app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
      Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Resources", "UserFiles")),
    RequestPath = "/userfiles"
  });

  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseAuthorization();
```

I am not able to get this to work and trying to access these files without authentication always results in an unauthorized error.

Is there any way to setup StaticFiles outside of wwwroot and still ignore authentication policies, ie make it publicly accessible?

Answer (score 4):

My Program.cs file, you can check the middleware like below

```
app.UseStaticFiles();

//******************   we need the code below *****************************
var fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Resources", "UserFiles"));

var options = new FileServerOptions
{
    FileProvider = fileProvider,
    RequestPath = "/userfiles",
    EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true
};

app.UseFileServer(options);

//******************   we need the code above *****************************

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

app.UseRouting();


app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

**My Project**

[image]

**Test Result**

[image]

**Tips**

The .txt file can be accessed by default, if you have other type files, you need to all your asp.net core support this kind of MIME type. Or you can set it in your IIS.  If your asp.net core application(or iis --machine level ) not support this mime type, we will get 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the example was not completely correct.
I was using middleware which included the following call

```
  app.UseRouting();
```

If the UseStaticFiles call happens after that call then it returns as unauthorized. Moving UseStaticFiles to before that call keeps it public, even when the static files are outside of wwwroot.

So the following works fine.

```
void ConfigureMiddleware(IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceProvider services, IHostEnvironment environment) {
      
  app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
      Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Resources", "UserFiles")),
    RequestPath = "/userfiles"
  });
  
  app.UseRouting();

  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: If my answer useful to you, could you accept it as answer?