# How to handle the path to static files for local development and release in .NET Core web API

Tags: c#, directory, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0, static-files

I have a `mailService` that uses static .html files as email templates for sending emails.
My current directory structure looks like this:

```
Infrastructure (project name)
    Templates
        contact.html
        welcome.html
```

On localhost I get hold of the templates like this:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine("Infrastructure/Templates", templateType)))
```

Now when deploying the website, in the bin folder it does not deploy the `Infrastructure` as part of the directory (I assume it is because it is the actual project name). It only deploys the `Templates` folder with it's contents e.g. *wwwroot/templates/*.

How can I reference the `Templates` folder so that it will use the correct directory locally and when deployed?

Answer (score 0):

#### WAY 1 . STORE the files under wwwroot

I have share the sample code below, let me explain it briefly, by default the static files should be stored under the `wwwroot` folder. And we should use `_env.WebRootPath` to implement this. For more details, you can refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76970301/7687666).

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _youtube = new YoutubeClient();
        _env = env;
    }
    // 
    ...
    string diretorioDeSaida = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "templates");
```

#### WAY 2 . STORE the files under the main project

[image]

Then we should use it like below, for more details you can [check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76570788/7687666):

```
var fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Resources", "UserFiles"));

var options = new FileServerOptions
{
    FileProvider = fileProvider,
    RequestPath = "/userfiles",
    EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true
};

app.UseFileServer(options);
```

---

The ways above, we still need to double check the .csproj file, we need to make sure the folder which we needed are exist after deployment.

[ASP.NET Core: Exclude or include files on publish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42713770/7687666)

Comment: I cannot move the files outside of the project. I ended up using conditional pre-processor to determine `Debug` or not.

Comment: Hi @Jnr, I can't  get your point, there are two ways in my solution, it is recommened to use way 1 to fix the issue.